# How to add SwipeRefreshLayout to WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, swiperefreshlayout

I need to pull from the top to refresh my web view 
I found this on Android Developer site but i don't know how to use it

xml Code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java code

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");

        // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
        // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
        myUpdateOperation();
    }
}
```

);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gotta put your WebView inside SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    String currentUrl = "https://news.ycombinator.com/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

        webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
            }
        });


    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            currentUrl = url;
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }


}
```

`swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` stops the animation.

Comment: Ok thanks mister byt know there is probem know in this code it dosen't refreshing the website just but it's moving back to the home page it's not reloading this webpage it's moving back to the root url that given again so now we need to access to the current webview url so please can you help me with that

Comment: First of all, not a mister. Let's drop the prejudice. Secondly, you can check the edited code and you're welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't change anything for me for Ex. if have a            String currentUrl = "youtube.com"; and your webview is in this url "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4y0KOeXViI" so if you do a refresh for this site so it will back to the original webpage url that given inside the currentUrl

Comment: Hımm, yep this trick doesn't work with javascript. Because it doesn't change url. I don't know how to refresh content in this scenerio.

Comment: don;t agree with this answer, after page finished, refresher can not showing his animation whenever refreshing webview

Answer (score 1):

To be able to refresh the page with the same URL running

1. you gotta save your link in ISharedPreferences when page first loaded

   ```
   public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
   {
       ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
       editor.PutString("MyURL", url);
       editor.Commit();
   }
   ```
2. when you load the URL for reffresh use the saved URL

   ```
   string SaveURL = prefs.GetString("MyURL", "");
   webView.loadUrl(SaveURL);
   ```

   -- Other Solution is 
    `Webview.Reload();` // This code  Refreshes the current page loaded